# Are return types copied in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how return works in Python and whether a move operation is being used behind the scenes. Consider the following code:

```py
def get_graph(maze): # maze is a 2D bool matrix, with True representing walls
    nrow = len(maze)
    ncol = len(maze[0])
    graph = {}
    for row in range(nrow):
        for col in range(ncol):
            edges = []
            if col - 1 != -1 and maze[row][col-1] is False:
                edges.append((row, col-1))  # left_edge
            if col + 1 != ncol and maze[row][col+1] is False:
                edges.append((row, col+1))  # right_edge
            if row - 1 != - 1 and maze[row-1][col] is False:
                edges.append((row-1, col))  # top_edge
            if row + 1 != nrow and maze[row+1][col] is False:
                edges.append((row+1, col))  # bottom_edge
            graph[(row, col)] = edges
    return graph
```

Would `graph` be moved to `g` in below code? I assume no deep copy is being performed here.

```py
mat=[[False, False, False, False],
       [True, True, False, True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]]

g = get_graph(mat)
```

Comment: Dont understand your question. It is just an assignment. What do you mean by `be moved to`?

Comment: The assignment operator `=` creates only references in Python.

Comment: In C++, if the function is like ``unordered_map<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>> get_graph(const vector<vector<bool>> &maze)`` the return type is getting copied.

Comment: No, *python **never** copies anything implicitly*. Read and understand the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has no concept of memory locations or the 'moving' of data.

It has two concepts: objects and names.

As far as a user of Python is considered, objects live in a magic cloud, automatically delete themselves when no longer necessary and never move.

Names are created by the assignment operator. When I say `a = 5`, that does not mean that now `a` 'contains' the object 5 or that it has 'moved to a', it means I simply created a new name `a` for the object on the right hand side, which is 5.

Similarly, `g = f()` for arbitrary function `f` takes whatever object `f` returned and makes `g` a name for that object. It does not copy or move anything.

Comment: If ``a = {5: 10, 12: 15}`` or something, and then later ``a = 5`` would the ``{5: 10, 12 : 15}`` object be deleted then?

Comment: @nathanesau An object in Python is deleted if there are no references left to it. If `a` was the only thing referring to that dictionary, then yes, it will be deleted.

Comment: @nathanesau Python the *language* only says that objects that are no longer referenced by anything are eligible for garbage collection. CPython (the *implementation* you are likely using) uses reference counting as a garbage collection strategy, and objects are reclaimed as immediately as soon as their reference count drops to zero.

Comment: OK, so in my example, ``graph`` is a name referencing some object somewhere in the magic cloud. And then ``g`` is name referencing the **same** object somewhere in the magic cloud. OK this is a good explanation.

Comment: @nathanesau again, you should really read nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html *especially* if you are used to a language like C++ where variables and assignment have very different semantics. Python's model is simple, very simple, but different from C++.

Comment: It seems to me the "similar" C++ way to write the code is ``using graph = unordered_map<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>>`` and then inside the function allocate memory with ``unique_ptr<graph> gr = make_unique<graph>(...)``. Then when calling the function, use ``unique_ptr<graph> g = get_graph(...)``. There would be a move performed. Is this an accurate comparison between the languages?

Comment: @nathanesau if that is returning a pointer, then yes, but again, you should really just try to understand Python on it's own terms. Python *doesn't have pointers*.

Answer (score 2):

You  seem to be thinking of variables as *containers* of data, when they are better thought of as *references* to data, so that the *object* doesn't get moved so much as a reference to that object gets copied, hopefully making clear why no copy (deep or otherwise) is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Do an experiment: If you put `print(id(graph))` immediately before the return and put `print(id(g))` immediately after the assignment, the same `id` will be printed, showing that it is only a reference which is returned. This returned reference will prevent the graph from being garbage-collected, which is the usual fate of local variables after a function return.